# Data Mapping -- Hotel

Tags: java, sql

Currently I have two data separately listed by hotel name, country, city and zip code. While I have another list of data that contains the same but needs to be mapped and matched to the original one.

For example,

First data has:

```
Name: Sheraton 
Country: USA
City: Dallas
Zip Code: 31141
```

While the other data has:

```
Name: Sheraton hotel 
Country: USA 
City: Dallas
Zip code: 31141
```

Is there a way where I would have the ability to execute some queries where I would be able to map "shearton hotel" from the second data and map it to the orginal where it has "sheraton" considering the data is more than 87K.

Looking forward for a way to do it.

Comment: You have two tables? What SQL engine? Is the only difference that the second table has " hotel" after the name?

Comment: Sounds like you need to normalize your database.

Comment: How is this question related to Java?

Comment: I have two separate databases. No, it could be a comma or space as well.@Blorgbeard

Comment: They are running in a java environment @jpw

Comment: Yes normalizing the data @MonadNewb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect the two tables you can use an inner join but how you do the join depends on how your data maps to each other and without knowing this I don't think anyone here can give you more advice. If it's as simple as the `name` field in the second table always is the same as the `name`field in the first table, plus some random extra chars you could probably do something like this:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.name LIKE table1 + '%' 
AND table1.Country = table2.country 
AND table1.city = table2.city 
AND table1.[Zip code] = table2.[Zip code]
```

Where the mapping is done in the `table2.name LIKE table1 + '%'`part of the join. 
This will of course give odd results if there are more than two hotels that share a common name base and the other identifiers...

This answer is based on speculation though as you haven't provided much information on the table design or how the items map to each other.